# How can I represent Multidimensional array in msg format

Tags: ros, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If i have something like

```
int  mein[NUM][4];
```

in C++. How do I represent it in msg format.
Should it be something like

```
uint8[][4] mein
```

Also as NUM is defined in my C++ file and can vary according to certain parameters. Should I just allocate it dynamically in msg format or I should give it a certain value or define NUM in msg format. Do you think there would be any disadvantage if I just allocate it dynamically meaning like `uint8[][4] mein`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73711/how-can-i-represent-multidimensional-array-in-msg-format/) by [micheal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5403/micheal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2013-08-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi michael,

you can probably use the [std_msgs/ByteMultiArray](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/MultiArrayDimension.html). You can define a [MultiArrayLayout](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/MultiArrayLayout.html) which considers the NUM size. Examples are given in the linked documentations.

I am not really used to C++, so I can't really help you with the allocation question.

---

Originally posted by [Josch](https://answers.ros.org/users/3932/josch/) with karma: 230 on 2013-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5